# How to create mouse wheel scroll counter

Tags: javascript, mousewheel

How can I count mouse scroll using pure JS?
Example:

> default value: 0
> scroll down:  ++1
> scroll up: --1

I tried to do this using `deltaY` and a switch case

```js
let mouseWheel = 0;
switch (deltaY) {
  case 100:
    if (mouseWheel > 0) {
      mouseWheel += 1;
    } else if (mouseWheel < 0) {
      mouseWheel = 0;
    }
    break;
  case -100:
    if (mouseWheel > 0) {
      mouseWheel -= 1;
    } else if (mouseWheel < 0) {
      mouseWheel = 0;
    }
    break;
  default:
    break;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [wheel event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/wheel_event) to detect for mouse wheel changes and add/deduct the counter accordingly.

My example assumes you are only checking vertical scrolling (i.e. change in deltaY). Feel free to amend the code if you need to check horizontal scroll too.

I think you don't want to hard code the deltaY change (e.g. 100 or -100) because different people may have configured a different scroll amount and this would break your `switch` statement.

```js
const containerEle = document.querySelector("#container")

let mouseWheelCounter = 0;

containerEle.addEventListener("wheel", (wheel) => {
  if(wheel.deltaY > 0) {
    mouseWheelCounter++;
  }else{
    mouseWheelCounter--;
  }
  console.log(mouseWheelCounter) 
})
```

Here's an [example with JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/o62013dy/)

Answer (score 1):

- Get the [`deltaY` from the WheelEvent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WheelEvent/deltaY)
- Use [Math.sign()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/sign) to get the respective `-1` or `1` value
- Use [Math.max()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/max) to prevent values below `0`

```js
let mouseWheel = 0;

addEventListener("wheel", (evt) => {
  mouseWheel += Math.sign(evt.deltaY);  // Add or subtract 1
  mouseWheel = Math.max(0, mouseWheel); // Prevent negative value
  console.log(mouseWheel);
});
```

```html
Scroll down and up
```

Answer (score -1):

As others have said before, you are looking for the [wheel](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/wheel_event) event.
This event listens for rotation on mousewheel (or other pointing devices) and then allows you to access it's `deltaY` property, which tells you "how far" the user has scrolled.

You might also want to use `deltaMode` just to make sure you are using proper units.

```
let mouseWheel = 0;

window.addEventListener('wheel', function(event) {
    if (event.deltaY > 0) {
        mouseWheel ++; // scroll down
    } else if (event.deltaY < 0) {
        mouseWheel--; // scroll up
    }
    console.log(count);
}, false);
```